# Am I using jquery getJSON correctly? Nothing appears on the page in godaddy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cross-domain, jsonp

I have a json file and an index file that uses jquery 1.10 getJSON and I'm trying to get data from the json file to display. I've got it to work on my localhost but when I move the index file to the subdomain **mbsk8.zerogravity-web.com** and the JSON file to the base domain **www.zerogravity-web.com**, the section of the page that is supposed to be updated is blank. This leads me to believe that this is a cross domain request issue.

No values are being added to console.log either.

Here is what I've tried to handl cross domain requests:

- Added **"?callback=?"** to the end of the URL
- Added a name around the JSON object: **jsonResponse(JSON formatted object)**

The folder structure on my godaddy account is:

**json file:** /LloydIce/json/skschedule.json

**index file:** /LloydIce/m/index.html (m) is the subdomain for mobile, using jquery mobile

**Code for index.html**

**Header section for jquery resources**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Script section in header**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#OpenSkate',function() {
$('#publicHolder').empty();
    $.getJSON('http://www.zerogravity-web.com/LloydIce/json/skschedule.json?callback=?',function(data)
{
  $.each(data, function(index, data){

    var collapsible = $('<div data-role="collapsible"></div>');
    console.log(this.day);
    collapsible.append('<h2>' + this.day + '</h2>');


      $.each(data.activities, function(index, data){
        if(this.type === "Public"){
        console.log(this.notes + ", " + this.activity);
        collapsible.append('<p><strong>' + this.activity + '</strong></p>');


        $.each(data.times, function(index, data){
          collapsible.append('<p><strong>Start:</strong> ' + this.start + ', <strong>End:</strong> ' + this.end + '</p></div>');

                    });
                    }
                });
            var collapsibleSet = $("#publicHolder");
            collapsibleSet.append(collapsible);
            collapsibleSet.trigger('create');
            });

        }); 
    });
```

**Code for JSON file:**

```
jsonResults(
[
    {
    "day": "Monday",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Class",
            "notes": "Ages 3-5",
            "activity": "Snowbunnies 1 ",
            "times": [
                {"start":"6:00 PM","end":"6:45 PM"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Public",
            "notes": "N/A",
            "activity": "Open Skate ",
            "times": [
                {"start":"11:30 AM","end":"5:00 PM"},
                {"start":"7:30 PM","end":"9:30 PM"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
);
```

**chrome dev tools Network - Header tab**

```
   Request URL:http://www.zerogravity-web.com/LloydIce/json/skschedule.json?callback=jQuery110206146174017339945_1388711470249&_=1388711470252
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=183972909.883508564.1382898602.1388360907.1388663932.3; __utmz=183972909.1382898602.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:www.zerogravity-web.com
Referer:http://mbsk8.zerogravity-web.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jQuery110206146174017339945_1388711470249
_:1388711470252
Response Headersview source
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mbsk8.zerogravity-web.com
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://mbsk8.zerogravity-web.com
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:563
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 03 Jan 2014 01:48:53 GMT
ETag:"233-4ef071c1e30e4"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Fri, 03 Jan 2014 01:48:42 GMT
Server:Apache
```

**Chrome dev tools Network - preview and response tabs:**

```
jsonResults(
[
    {
        "day": "Monday",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Class",
                "notes": "Ages 3-5",
                "activity": "Snowbunnies 1 ",
                "times": [
                    {"start":"6:00 PM","end":"6:45 PM"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Public",
                "notes": "N/A",
                "activity": "Open Skate ",
                "times": [
                    {"start":"11:30 AM","end":"5:00 PM"},
                    {"start":"7:30 PM","end":"9:30 PM"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
);
```

**Chrome dev tools console**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonResults is not defined skschedule.json?callback=jQuery110206146174017339945_1388711470249&_=1388711470252:1
(anonymous function)
```

**If I remove the jsonResults from the JSON  file the information in the Network preview tab looks like this**

```
[{day:Monday,...}]
    0: {day:Monday,…}
activities: [{type:Class, notes:Ages 3-5, activity:Snowbunnies 1 , times:[{start:6:00 PM, end:6:45 PM}]},…]
0: {type:Class, notes:Ages 3-5, activity:Snowbunnies 1 , times:[{start:6:00 PM, end:6:45 PM}]}
activity: "Snowbunnies 1 "
notes: "Ages 3-5"
times: [{start:6:00 PM, end:6:45 PM}]
0: {start:6:00 PM, end:6:45 PM}
end: "6:45 PM"
start: "6:00 PM"
type: "Class"
1: {type:Public, notes:N/A, activity:Open Skate ,…}
activity: "Open Skate "
notes: "N/A"
times: [{start:11:30 AM, end:5:00 PM}, {start:7:30 PM, end:9:30 PM}]
0: {start:11:30 AM, end:5:00 PM}
end: "5:00 PM"
start: "11:30 AM"
1: {start:7:30 PM, end:9:30 PM}
end: "9:30 PM"
start: "7:30 PM"
type: "Public"
day: "Monday"
```

After all that, I'm still not getting the results to appear on my page.

Comment: did you look in the browser console "Chrome" on the network tab if there is any information that could help ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to pass the results of day to the console but it only showed a red "GET" and then the URL that I am targeting. When I expand the arrow in the console it shows a lot of jquery information. I'm not sure what to look for in all of that.

Comment: Ok, I misread your comment. Thanks for pointing that out. It helped, not I need to figure out how to interpret it. I see in the preview tab everything that I want to appear in the page. However, nothing appears in the page. Does that bring anything to mind? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

since you add jsonResults to wrap your json data, this becomes a jsonp request, not an ajax request anymore. please google "difference between ajax and jsonp".

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : your url,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback : 'jsonResults',
    ......
});
```

Comment: Ok, possibly silly question here. To use getJSON for cross domain requests, do I need to use a server side language such as PHP or JAVA? For some reason, I think I'm missing some key ingredient to make this work. I am under the impression that all I need is a .JSON file on one domain and an index.html on another domain, and that I can get and display the values from the .JSON file using getJSON in my index.html file. Is my impression wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: add a function named jsonResults in your page, in this function, do things that you want to do when the request get response. 
 window.jsonResults = function(ret){//ret here is your json data}

Comment: i see your url response here.
[http://www.zerogravity-web.com/LloydIce/json/skschedule.json](http://www.zerogravity-web.com/LloydIce/json/skschedule.json)
wrap the data with jsonResults() like you did before.